# PHP - uploading to dir outside docroot

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have nginx+php-fastcgi running on my server and I"m trying to allow a php script in /var/www/contest to upload to a non-public directory located at /var/www/private/uploads.

I've tried changing the include path in php.ini but all I get is "No input file specified." when I try to view the page in /contest that uploads the pics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your php script will run as some user. give that user write access to /var/www/private/uploads.

Answer (score 0):

At first, check your `upload_tmp_dir` in PHP_INI system and set to right path.
Check write permissions for it.
Use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to store files manually in right place.